# WiFi problem in Ubuntu 18.04.1: "activation of network connection failed"

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1. 
My WiFi driver is `rtl8723be`. It was working fine up until yesterday. Now, maybe after an update, I am getting a pop up :

`Connection failed. Activation of network connection failed`

and my WiFi is not working anymore. Here is my [wireless-info.txt](https://pastebin.com/i5Dq1bav)

I can connect to open WiFi hotspots, but cannot connect to secured networks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR = Remove your wifi access point connection, then reconnect.

Hi. I've recently got the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, albeit my wifi driver is different. Here is how I fixed it:

1. Open "**Settings**"
2. Choose "**Wi-Fi**" tab
3. In "**Visible networks**" list click on cogwheel icon next to your Wi-Fi access point
4. Click "**Forget connection**"
5. Now select your Wi-Fi access point, enter Wi-Fi password and click "**Connect**"